# How do I get a question semi-protected?

Tags: support, protected-posts

I've got a question getting lots of me-too answers, how can I get it semi-protected so that only established users can add answers?

- [How to save a rotated Adobe PDF file](https://superuser.com/q/145696/9461)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider it done.

The ideal approach would have been to **flag** the non-answers. Once the third answer by a new user is deleted, a question is automatically protected by the system.

If a question doesn't have more than three deleted answers, it generally shouldn't be protected. We don't want to artificially block users from posting valid solutions.